# webpack module federation and single-spa-vue with vue 2.16.12 not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, single-spa

I'm developing a microfront with single-spa-vue and Vue 2.6.12 and it's not working at all.

I'm using webpack module federation plugin.

This is my entry point.

```
src/app.ts

import singleSpaVue from 'single-spa-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';

import Main from './Main.vue';
import router from './router';

const lifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  Vue,
  appOptions: {
    render(h: any) {
      return h(Main as any);
    },
    router,
  } as any,
});

export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;
```

This is my webpack.config.js file

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')
const StandaloneSingleSpaPlugin = require('standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

const path = require('path');
const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index',
  cache: false,

  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',

  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },

  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3002/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '~' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    }
  },

  devServer: {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    contentBase: outputPath,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new StandaloneSingleSpaPlugin({
      // required
      appOrParcelName: "body",
      // optional - strongly encouraged for single-spa applications
      activeWhen: ['/'],
      // optional - defaults to true - turns on or off import-map-overrides.
      importMapOverrides: true,
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'content',
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'content' },
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        content: 'content'
      },
      exposes: {
        Content: './src/app',
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

And this is my index.ts file

```
src/index.ts

import { start, registerApplication } from 'single-spa'

registerApplication({
  name: 'content',
  app: () => import('content/Content' as any),
  activeWhen: '/',
},)

start()
```

And when I run **yarn start** and go to **localhost:3002** this is the error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTLwI.png)

Does anyone can help me plz?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well，may be u mixing the relationship with the host container and remote container, I saw your `ModuleFederationPlugin` config that special `remotes` and `name` is same, it seen like not correct.